# Flasks - render_template not rendering the html page

Tags: python, flask

I need help on the below code.

```
root@ip-xxxxxxxx:~/flaskapp# cat flaskapp.py
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/hello')
def hello_world():
    return render_template('testing.html', name = 'john')
    if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
root@ip-xxxxxxx:~/flaskapp#
```

When I am opening my site (http://www.example.com/hello), the page is returning 500 Internal Server Error.
Can someone be able to assist whats wrong with the code ?
 The above file (flaskapp.py) is under folder flaskapp which is under the html root directory. Also the testing.html is placed under the templates folder inside the flaskapp folder.

Below is the content of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
WSGIDaemonProcess flaskapp threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/flaskapp/flaskapp.wsgi

<Directory flaskapp>
WSGIProcessGroup flaskapp
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

below is the apache error log

File "/var/www/html/flaskapp/flaskapp.py", line 8
    app.run()
      ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: I think you need to check Apache error log

Comment: What does the flask logs say?

Comment: @CrazyElf - have edited the code with apache error log

Comment: The `if __name__ == "__main__"` block is indented underneath the `hello_world()` function definition.  It shouldn't be.

Comment: @CrazyElf & marxmacher - Thanks a lot guys for the help. I checked the apache error log and found that it was an indent related issue. I have fixed it and nto the code is working as expected

Answer (score 2):

`File "/var/www/html/flaskapp/flaskapp.py", line 8 app.run() ^ IndentationError: expected an indented block`

Apache is telling you that there was an error reading line 8 in `flaskapp.py` because of indentation issues. [Python is very sensitive with regards to indentation.](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html) You have:

```py
    if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

Hope this helps!

`app.run()` should be indented further so that it appears to be "under" the if statement. Try changing your code to look like the following and see if this fixes it:

```py
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run()
```